# Please explain CodeIgniter ActiveRecord set() update()

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I can't seem to find a clear explanation in the user guide.

In CodeIgniter Active record, to update a table row, it appears that one needs to do three things: (1) identify the record(s) to be updated, (2) define what needs to change and (3) commit the changes.

Somehow, no matter how I read the manual, that is not clear. 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update

It seems to imply that "set" is about inserting - which means adding rows to the table in my books.

And "update" is about "changing" existing information.

The only way that works for me is to do all three actions.

Like this:

```
$this->db->where('id',$userid);         //selecting the right user
$this->db->set($SubscriptionChoices);   //setting the new values to be written
$this->db->update('userprefs');         //Do it. Update table userprefs
```

Answer (score 0):

so what you are calling 'set' -- its just the specific fields that you are updating and the values you are using. like from a simple form to update a name

```
    $updatedata = array(
        'first' => $this->input->post( 'first', TRUE ),
        'last' => $this->input->post( 'last', TRUE ),
        'statuscheck' => 'Name updated' 
        );
```

and then pass that data and the record id to a method to do the update

```
function update( $id, $updatedata ) {

    $this->db->where( 'id', $id );
    $this->db->update( 'yourtablename', $updatedata );

    if ( $this->db->affected_rows() == '1' ) {return TRUE;}

    else {return FALSE;}

} //
```

note one little annoying detail - if you update a record - with the same information - like in this case if someone updated the record but the first and last name are the same - then it will return 'false' - because nothing was updated.

so if you include a field in the update array like date time seconds that will always be different - then you won't have that issue.

Comment: yeah, but my point is that I couldn't get that to work. It kept complaining that I had to use "set()". so when you say `->db->where` and then `->db->update` I found I had to use `->db->where` then `->db->set` and then `->db->update`. That's what I don't get.

Comment: The code above works. It sounds like there was an issue with the data array you were passing to the update method. Try something simple to test.

Answer (score 0):

It's Bit late But Others can get help.

you can use this in single function also.

```
$updatedata = array(
    'first' => $this->input->post( 'first', TRUE ),
    'last' => $this->input->post( 'last', TRUE ),
    'statuscheck' => 'Name updated' 
    );


function update( $id, $updatedata ) {

    $where = array( 'id' => $id );

    $this->db->update( 'yourtablename', $updatedata , $where);

    if ( $this->db->affected_rows() == '1' ) {return TRUE;}

    else {return FALSE;}
} //
```

But instead of using this you can also use below class which provides CRUD functionality.

https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model

Answer (score 0):

This works to update by using set in `ci.` model part.

*Example*:

```
public function change_province_value()
{
    $this->db->where('customer_zone',0);         
    $this->db->set('customer_zone',NULL);  
    $query = $this->db->update('customer');
    return $query;
}
```